# Storing data to database and user registration

Tags: user-meta, user-registration, users

The project that I'm working with have a quote form. When someone submit the quote request, the information should be stored into a new table in the database and also prompt the user to register an account (Register as a WordPress subscriber) in that website. When they register, the user Id must be passed into the lead information table such as user id so that we can track the leads per user.

Here is what I completed. All the lead info are stored into the database. Then prompt the user to register and it works fine as well. The only thing which I'm not sure how to do is - collecting the user id after user registration and storing it into the corresponding row in the lead info table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some of your code regarding registration and Lead table information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you need used hook [user_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/)

it's return to you user id, after that you can save it in DB.